# .NET API for DirectAccess status

Tags: .net, powershell

we are currently developing a .NET application that needs to know the Microsoft DirectAccess connection state. I know it is possible to query the status via the PowerShell command `Get-DAConnectionStatus`.

But is it also possibly to query this DirectAccess status via a managed .NET library/API? A workaround would be to run a PowerShell script from C# but I don't think this is ideal from a performance perspective (we need to check this status regularly).

Comment: It seems like something you would want to query once when you are configuring your server and after that not again so writing code to return the status seems like something that not needed (IMO). Maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine the following (not testet yet though):

You can query the same information via

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root/StandardCimv2" MSFT_DAConnectionStatus
```

and you can query `CIM` instances by C# via the assembly `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` of the `Windows SDK` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn313203(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I came up with this C# code which works on machines with and without DirectAccess:

```
/// <summary>
/// </summary>
/// <returns>-1 if DA is not available on this system.</returns>
private int GetDAStatus()
{
  int status = -1;

  string NamespacePath = @"\\.\ROOT\StandardCimv2";
  string ClassName = "MSFT_DAConnectionStatus";
  try
  {
    ManagementClass oClass = new ManagementClass(NamespacePath + ":" + ClassName);
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in oClass.GetInstances())
    {
      status = Convert.ToInt32(mo["Status"]);
      break;
    }
  }
  catch (System.Management.ManagementException mex)
  {
    if (mex.ErrorCode == ManagementStatus.InvalidNamespace)
    {
      status = -1;
    }
    else throw;
  }
  return status;
}
```

Comment: `/// <returns>-1 if DA is not available on this system.</returns>` this is bad, you should return a bool in this situation. This is the recommended approach while working in C#/.NET, which is different to C conventions. So the method should be called something like "IsDirectAccessAvaliable()"

Comment: You are correct user9993, I did provide a public 'get' property for this: IsDirectAccessEnabled() which calls into GetDAStatus(). The private function is not exposed but is used elsewhere to access the real DirectAccess status (if available).